# Program not printing the expected exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, user-input

I am working on a program that will extract a text from a file like so:

```
NAME OF PROGRAM: text.txt

CONTENTS OF FILE:

  1: 101010100101010101 1010010101010101 101010101010101
  2: 0101010101 1010011010 10101010 10101010 10101010
  3: 0001000101010 10101010 10101010 1010101010 10101

START LINE: 1
END LINE: 2

results.txt generated.
```

I am at the part where the program will ask for the name of the program and I plan to use exceptions when the name of the program has the length of zero.

The program should have ran like:

```
NAME OF PROGRAM: 

THE NAME OF THE PROGRAM SHOULD NOT BE LESS THAN 1! [LEN_ERROR]
```

But the program run like so:

```
NAME OF PROGRAM:
THERE'S SOMETHING WRONG WITH YOUR INPUT! [INP_ERROR]
```

Here's the code:

```
class Program:
    """
      Author       : Alexander B. Falgui (alexbfalgui.github.io)
      Program Name : Text Extractor
      Description  : Takes an integer or string as an input and generates a
      text file with the extracted data. 

      Note: This program can be used, shared, modified by anyone.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.menu_file_loc = "menu"
        return self.load_files()

    def load_files(self):
        #self.menu_file = open(self.menu_file_loc)
        #self.read_mf = self.menu_file.read()

        return self.main_menu()

    def main_menu(self):
        #print(self.read_mf)
        print("""  [1] Extract Data\n  [2] Exit""")

        while (True):
            try:
              self.menu_input = input("CHOOSE AN OPTION> ")
              if (self.menu_input == 1):
                  try:
                    self.program_name = raw_input("\nNAME OF THE PROGRAM: ")
                    self.program_name = open(self.program_name)
                  except IOError:
                    if (len(program_name) == 0):
                      print("THE NAME OF THE PROGRAM SHOULD NOT BE LESS THAN"),
                      print(" 1! [LEN_ERROR]")

                    print("%s does not exist" % self.program_name)
              elif (self.menu_input == 0):
                  print("\n")
                  break

            except SyntaxError:
                continue
            except NameError:
                print("SOMETHING'S WRONG WITH YOUR INPUT. [INP_ERROR]\n")

# Run the program
Program()
```

Why did the program print the wrong exception and what can I do to fix that?

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3? Because in Py3, there is no `raw_input`, which is probably the `NameError` that is raised.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7 and the operating system is Debian 7.5 Wheezy. I am running the program via terminal typing in the form of `python program_name.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please** don't do `except SyntaxError: continue`, because you will silently go over any kind of syntax error.

To get more information about what's going wrong, you should `except NameError as e` to investigate further. See also https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

You should change the `except NameError`-part to the following:

```
        except NameError as e:
            print e
            print("SOMETHING'S WRONG WITH YOUR INPUT. [INP_ERROR]\n")
```

and you will see what really goes wrong.

Comment: Does this even attempt to answer the questions? You just made a comment and refer OP to an external source with out any explanation.

Comment: I included the relevant part of the external source in the answer. I agree that this answer would almost be suited as a comment as well.

Comment: I think it is even more suited as a comment. You do not answer the question. I did, but obviously was wrong, so I deleted it =). IMO one should answer only with a correction and explanation. If you just have an idea how to solve it - it's a comment. Honestly, I dunno, this is a "find a bug in my code" question, so maybe ideas are fine too as answers, because it's extremely hard to write a good answer if the bug isn't obvious.

Comment: @user3839951 "you didn't tell me what to read" -- when in doubt, read all of it. But see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me found the bug. I was feeling tired that I couldn't see the error.

Comment: It was one line 32 where I tested the length `program_name` instead of `self.program_name`. I followed your advice by modifying `except NameError` as you said and found the error right away which says `program_name` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you added those two exception handler at the end but you are getting a Name Exception because your refer to the **program_name** variable instead of **self.program_name**

Change your line `if (len(program_name) == 0):` to `if (len(self.program_name) == 0):` and it should work.

Comment: That solves the problem but I found the error thanks to @Jasper. I'd upvote your answer if I have enough reputation.